# Java Alarm program not running

Tags: java, netbeans

So i got this code for an alarm program made with java off the internet and there are still errors am not sure how to fix, because i am new to java programming.
i was hoping i could get help with this, thanks.

```
package alarm;


import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class Alarm { Thread t; int str = 0;
public void checkAlarm(int h,int m,final String ampm,final String message)
{ final int a=h,b=m;

if(ampm.equals("AM"))
{
str=0;
}
else if(ampm.equals("PM"))
{
str=1;
}
final boolean whileloop=true;
t=new Thread(){ public void run(){ while(whileloop==true) 
{ Calendar d=new GregorianCalendar(); int hours=d.get(Calendar.HOUR); 
int   mins=d.get(Calendar.MINUTE); int str1=d.get(Calendar.AM_PM); 
if(a==hours&&b==mins&&str==str1) 
{ // AlarmClock ac=new AlarmClock(null,true); try { JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Alarm Works!"); // ac.getAlarm(message); break; } catch (IOException ex) { } } } }

};
t.setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);
t.start();
} public static void main(String ar[])
{
Alarm a=new Alarm();
a.checkAlarm(4,58,"AM","XD");
}
```

Comment: What are the errors?

Answer (score 0):

It was hard for me to read the code so I tried to clean it up a bit. Seems its part of a bigger picture. I imagine the Alarm class is a part (member) of AlarmClock, that is mentioned in the commented part of the code. Or Alarm is an inner class of AlarmClock? At least thats how I would imagine it to be. Since it calls getAlarm(). Weird with it calling that method with "message" as argument as well. Unless theres a reference to AlarmClock in the class which there isn't. I would prefer getAlarm().getMessage().
But then I would make the AlarmClock have a running thread rather then the Alarm. I dunno. Hard to say when I don't know the whole picture. Anyways. tried to clean it up and make some kind of working piece of it.

This might be cpu intensive. There should also be a stopper method to stop the thread and probably a lot of other stuff. This is in no way a correct answer, just me trying to hopefully shed some light. Maybe you could come with more info or code that is part of it?

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

public class Alarm2 {

    private int str = 0;
    private int a;
    private int b;
    private Thread t; 
    private volatile boolean whileloop = true;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Alarm2 a = new Alarm2();
        a.checkAlarm(4,36,"AM","XD");
    }

    public void checkAlarm(int h,int m, String ampm, String message) {
        this.a = h;
        this.b = m;

        if(ampm.equals("AM")) {
            str=0;
        }
        else if(ampm.equals("PM")) {
            str=1;
        }

        t = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                while(whileloop == true) {
                    Calendar d = new GregorianCalendar(); 
                    int hours = d.get(Calendar.HOUR); 
                    int mins = d.get(Calendar.MINUTE); 
                    int str1 = d.get(Calendar.AM_PM);

                    if((a == hours) && (b == mins) && (str == str1)) { 
                        // AlarmClock ac=new AlarmClock(null,true); try { JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Alarm Works!"); // ac.getAlarm(message); break; } catch (IOException ex) { } } } }
                        System.out.println("Ring Ring!!!! Alarm working :)");
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        t.setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);
        t.start();
    }
}
```